# Python pandas dataframe : In an array column, if first item contains specific string then remove that item from array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has some column like below which contains arrays of different sizes:

```
column
["a_id","b","c","d"]
["d_ID","e","f"]
["h","i","j","k","l"]
["id_m","n","o","p"]
["ID_q","r","s"]
```

I want to remove first item from the array of every row if the first item contains "ID" or "id". So, expected output will look like:

```
column
["b","c","d"]
["e","f"]
["h","i","j","k","l"]
["n","o","p"]
["r","s"]
```

How do we check for this in the column containing array elements in the dataframe?

Comment: Nikita if you want help quicker you should always share your data with us in a correct manner. Try using print(df.to_dict()) to share it here or to limit to 5 rows. df.head().to_dict().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str[0]` for select first values in list and then check `ID` by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
m = df['column'].str[0].str.contains('ID', case=False)
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: column, dtype: bool
```

And then remove it by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with `str[1:]`:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].mask(m, df['column'].str[1:])
print (df)
            column
0        [b, c, d]
1           [e, f]
2  [h, i, j, k, l]
3        [n, o, p]
4           [r, s]
```

Comment: I added timings in my answer... take a look please!

Comment: @jezrael , there is a possibility after doing this "m = df['column'].str[0].str.contains('ID', case=False)", it may return NaN for few rows, so on doing this "df['column'] = df['column'].mask(m, df['column'].str[1:])" it will give some error. Any way to handle NaN's?

Comment: Yes, use only `.str.contains('ID', case=False, na=False)`

Comment: OP accepted this answer for whatever reason despite my answer being faster... guess all OPs don't care about timings ;)

Answer (score 4):

Edit: It seems I misread your question. This solution is meant to remove *any* element that has `'id'` in it, not just the first.

**Option 1**
I believe the most straightforward solution is using `apply`:

```
df

               col
0  [a_id, b, c, d]
1     [d_ID, e, f]
2  [h, i, j, k, l]
3  [id_m, n, o, p]
4     [ID_q, r, s]


df.col = df.col.apply(lambda y: (y[1:] if 'id' in y[0].lower() else y))

df
               col
0        [b, c, d]
1           [e, f]
2  [h, i, j, k, l]
3        [n, o, p]
4           [r, s]
```

---

**Option 2**
Alternatively, use a *list comprehension*:

```
df.col = [(y[1:] if 'id' in y[0].lower() else y)  for y in df.col]  

df

               col
0        [b, c, d]
1           [e, f]
2  [h, i, j, k, l]
3        [n, o, p]
4           [r, s]
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000)
```

```
%%timeit
m = df['col'].str[0].str.contains('ID', case=False)
df['col'].mask(m, df['col'].str[1:])

1 loop, best of 3: 917 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit [(y[1:] if 'id' in y[0].lower() else y)  for y in df.col]  
1 loop, best of 3: 272 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit df.col.apply(lambda y: (y[1:] if 'id' in y[0].lower() else y))
1 loop, best of 3: 309 ms per loop
```

Comment: @coldspeed, i want to check for "id" or "ID" only in first element of array

Comment: @NikitaGupta I added timings to my answer. It seems the list comp is quite fast.

Comment: with list comprehension method, I am getting error : TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Comment: @NikitaGupta Don't do `df.col`, do `df['col']`, I think that's your problem. Your column name is the same as a bound dataframe method, and there are name clashes. Also keep in mind the timings, if you want the most performance wise.